# How to identify the effects of treatments relative to a control group?

Tags: regression, experiment-design, survey, ordinal-data, treatment-effect

I am currently designing a vignette survey experiment with three conditions. Respondents will either be assigned to (a) the first treatment, (b) the second treatment, or (c) the control group. After reading the vignette, respondents will be asked to answer a few questions. Here is an example:

> How would you describe the governor's quality as a leader?
>
> 1. Excellent
> 2. Above average
> 3. Average
> 4. Below average
> 5. Very poor

Given the ordered nature of the set of responses, I will use ordinal regression to analyze the data. My goal is to identify the effect of the treatments relative to the control on subsequent survey responses. Here is my question: Should I just run a series of regressions with dummy variables corresponding to whether one was assigned to the treatment or control group? I'm just kinda confused as to the best way to analyze treatment effects. Any advice/resources would be helpful.